# Why does ASUS PROB550M-C boot only into BIOS?

Tags: cpu, bios, asus

I have setup a PC, I've installed an ASUS PROB550M-C, with
this passive cooler (used on three other PCS never had a problem)

[image]

I have disabled TPM and secure boot, I have set the fan monitor speed to ignore (otherwise the boot said CPU fan error press <kbd>F1</kbd>)

The PC boots… But only into BIOS, my disks are ignored and shows the BIOS screen like as I press <kbd>F2</kbd> (but, of course I don't press <kbd>F2</kbd>)!

No way to boot? I have tried to boot from UEFI CD and UEFI hard disk, now I try a legacy USB...

P.S. Answers with something like “…use a CPU fan silent lower RPM from…” and similar are not accepted, sorry, I hate noise, even low.

Comment: I read your post carefully.  You may wish to enable the Fan as a test and see if that allows the computer to boot.

Comment: All my other motherboards (Asus m5a97, Asrock b450m) boot all without cpu fan, why this don't boot?

Comment: I don't know (and cannot know) exactly.  Computers are sensitive to heat, so I am making a "trial and error" type of suggestion

Comment: Thanks for answer, was only a problem with uefi.

Comment: Since UEFI has been standard on computers for nearly a decade, that solution may work for you but it not a useful broad based solution.  UEFI and Secure Boot are needed for Windows 11 and Windows 10 support is ending in 2 years.

Comment: I'm a Linux user, I don't use Windows since the old good days of Xp (before sp1!). Nothing against Windows, but I prefer Linux, btw I will correct my message, instead of Solution i write..workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround found: I have enabled  CSM (Compatibility Support Module) in BIOS with all my mod option (control fan ignored).

Now boot fine in legacy mode (I don't care about UEFI, the important thing is to boot).

This workaround works on Linux (Slackware 15.0), I don't know what happens on Windows because I don't use Windows for decades.

Comment: I suggest you start caring about UEFI. You are peeing against the wind.